# What is $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{e^{\sin x}\cos(x)}{1+e^{\tan x}} \, dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form

I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381406/finding-the-definite-integral-int-02-pi-frace-sin-x-cosx1e) question. The integral has a special property, so it might possibly be evaluable? No one tried evaluating it, so I created this. Not very often I ask question like this, but here it is.

So what is,

$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{e^{\sin x}\cos(x)}{1+e^{\tan x}} \, dx$$

**A list of Naïve Ideas**

Sub $u=\sin(x)$ allows you to cancel the $\cos$.

Half angle substitution

List the obscure special function it equals.

Try contour integration ;) (just being stupid here)

(Disclaimer: I have no reason to believe this integral has closed form beyond the property mentioned in the link)

Comment: Is not necessary the modulus in the integral!

Comment: What is the reason for the absolute value, since sine is already positive on that interval?

Comment: @JohnMolokach If you look at the link, you can see he just copy-pasted the integral from that question and changed the bounds. In that question, the absolute value is necessary to enable a trick to calculate the integral - here, it isn't.

Comment: It may be of interest to note that, for $\phi(x) = e^{|\sin x|} \, \cos x$, $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\phi(x) \, dx}{1 + e^{\tan x}} \, dx = - \frac{1}{2} \, \int_{0}^{\pi} \tanh\left(\frac{\tan x}{2}\right) \, \phi(x) \, dx.$$

Comment: i have also no hope that this integral has a soiution in the known elementary functions

Comment: @Zach466920 The function does not have any obvious symmetry on $[0,\pi]$ and WA returns a numerical value only, not any recognizable form.  Have you tried a series solution approach or other function theoretic way forward?

Answer (score 1):

Extending a comment made earlier:

---

As the integral was first defined, with $\phi(x) = e^{|\sin x|} \, \cos x$, an identity was presented as, in corrected form,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\phi(x) \, dx}{1 + e^{\tan x}} = - \frac{1}{2} \, \int_{0}^{\pi} \tanh\left(\frac{\tan x}{2} \right) \, \phi(x) \, dx.
\end{align}
Wolfram Alpha provides a numerical value of $- .727486$ for the integral on the left and 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \tanh\left(\frac{\tan x}{2} \right) \, \phi(x) \, dx = 1.45497.
\end{align}
In either case the numerical values lead to the speculation that
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\phi(x) \, dx}{1 + e^{\tan x}} = - \frac{1}{2} \, \int_{0}^{\pi} \tanh\left(\frac{\tan x}{2} \right) \, \phi(x) \, dx \approx - \frac{672}{855}.
\end{align}
Further work can be done to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Not bad, (+1) thanks